# How to specify the dependent jars when submitting application

Tags: apache-flink

I am using following script to submit flink application,

`flink run -m  yarn-cluster -c com.my.flink.learningflink.FlinkToMySQL -yn 4 -ys 1 -j  /tmp/learing.flink.1.7.1-0.1.jar`

My class FlinkToMySQL  is in learing.flink.1.7.1-0.1.jar, but my application also needs to depend on mysql jar, how could I specify the mysql jar and other dependent jars.

Also, I tried the `-yt` option with following script

`flink run -m  yarn-cluster -c com.my.flink.learningflink.FlinkToMySQL -yn 4 -ys 1 -yt /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar -j  /tmp/learing.flink.1.7.1-0.1.jar`

,it still complains that no suitable driver found(runs well in my local IDE).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Flink supports multiple ways to ship user code jars:

- Build uber-jar which contains all user code dependencies
- Put dependencies into `FLINK_HOME/lib` which is shipped to the cluster
- When using Yarn, use `-yt` to specify additional files which should be shipped to the cluster and are added to the system's classpath

Comment: As you see in my question， I am using `-yt` to specify the jars,but it doesn' t work

Comment: Could you share the logs with me. I would like to see whether the classpath contains something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Build your jar with maven as a "jar with dependencies" and deploy that jar instead.

My maven build definition looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass></mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Sure，thanks @chris-gerken for the answer. I think Flink should have  the options to ship the separate dependent jars. But I will use the uber fat jar to move on with my work.